# Unity ScriptedImporter AssetImporters does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' on build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a program where I can open PDFs located in my Resource folder in my Assets.

It works fine out the box when I change the file extensions from ".pdf" to ".txt". However, I would rather not change it in order to load the resource as that adds additional tasks whenever new PDFs need to be added.

No, the resource will not load if the file extension is .pdf.

I followed some documentation to write my own importer for the .pdf extension and it works perfectly in the Unity editor. However, when I attempt to build, I get a bunch of namespace errors related to the importer I wrote.

Using **Unity 2021.1.12f1**

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.AssetImporters;
using UnityEngine;

[ScriptedImporter(1, "pdf")]
public class PDFImporter : ScriptedImporter
{
    public override void OnImportAsset(AssetImportContext ctx)
    {
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ctx.assetPath);
        PDFAsset pdfa = new PDFAsset(bytes);

        ctx.AddObjectToAsset("main", pdfa);
        ctx.SetMainObject(pdfa);
    }
}
```

Errors on build:

```
Assets\Editor\PDFImporter.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AssetImporters' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Assets\Editor\PDFImporter.cs(8,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ScriptedImporter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Editor\PDFImporter.cs(7,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ScriptedImporterAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Editor\PDFImporter.cs(7,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ScriptedImporter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets\Editor\PDFImporter.cs(10,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssetImportContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I followed some of the solutions [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-build-a-project-that-contains-scriptedimporter.721676/), but still receive those errors. I wasn't able to find any libraries to import into unity to use the experimental libraries as shown [in this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Experimental.AssetImporters.ScriptedImporter.GatherDependenciesFromSourceFile.html).

To be clear, I was running **Unity 2020.1.5f** and the documentation indicates I should have

> using UnityEditor.Experimental.AssetImporters

However, I wasn't able to find an easy location for Experimental stuff and, frankly, don't feel it's necessary since the **UnityEditor.AssetImporters** is available to me for use.

I updated Unity to the most recent 2021 version and attempt again just in case, but to no avail.

Comment: The Unity Editor scripts are stripped from the runtime dll.  If you need the functionality available at runtime, it cannot be in an Editor folder and cannot use things from UnityEditor (such as AssetDatabase) unless they are in a #if UNITY_EDITOR conditional compilation block.

Comment: This is easily visualized from within visual studio, if you look in the Solution Explorer, you will notice that all Editor scripts are in their own assembly within the solution.

Comment: Thanks @hijinxbassist. I was working off of like 3 hours of sleep with a newborn and it was this morning that I realized that this script isn't even needed for the build and that I could do as you said. I moved everything to my "scripts" folder and put the entire class inside the #if UNITY_EDITOR and it built and functioned perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to hijinxbassist I was able to get to the right conclusions about this problem.

I moved it from the Editor folder into my scripts folder. The following is the result of my changes to the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor.AssetImporters;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[ScriptedImporter(1, "pdf")]
public class PDFImporter : ScriptedImporter
{
    public override void OnImportAsset(AssetImportContext ctx)
    {
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ctx.assetPath);
        PDFAsset pdfa = new PDFAsset(bytes);

        ctx.AddObjectToAsset("main", pdfa);
        ctx.SetMainObject(pdfa);
    }
}
#endif
```